# Best way to perform SQL in ASP.NET

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

**The scenario**

I have a question about best practice and most efficient way of interacting with a SQL Server database from code behind in ASP.NET.

Currently I am writing an application for that has numerous forms for reading and writing to different SQL Server tables.

The way I have done it so far is by gathering info from codebehind of an aspx page and passing it to a specific class. For example:

In `Customer.aspx` page on `createNewCustomer_click` event I create a new instance of a class called `Customer` and gather customer info via properties. I then call an `insertNewCustomer` method in the `Customer` class to insert the info into the database.

```
public sub insertNewCustomer()
    dim sqlCommand as string="INSERT INTO CUSTOMER ([NAME],[REGNUM]) VALUES (@NAME,@REGNUM)"
    Dim paramName() as string={"NAME","REGNUM"}
    Dim paramValue() as object={_name,_regnum}     ' variables gathered via properties

   Dim sql as new CSQL(sqlCommand,paramName,paramValue,paramName.Count())
   sql.process()
end sub
```

So after I create a `SqlCommand` string, I create an array to hold parameter names and an array to hold parameter values.

I then pass that information to another class called `CSQL`, which creates an `SqlConnection`, a `SqlCommand` and adds `SqlParameter`.

**The problem**

The problem I am having is that this process is taking a lot of time to create a single form and every SQL operations. In addition it is difficult to maintain, for example if there is a change in the SQL table I need to change all the `SqlCommand` specified in the `Customer` class.

**The question**

What I am wondering about is how to create classes in vb.net to interact with a SQL Server database more effectively and taking less time to create, maintain and debug the code for them.

Comment: Look into Entity Framework

Comment: Thank you John. You mean using a dataset, dataTables and table adapters

Comment: No, he means to use Entity framework or something similar that would do most work for you. However, please note that there is nothing like "best approach", only the best approach for your current situation, needs, preferences etc. You have to make the call and choose the most appropriate in your case.

Comment: No, I mean using [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx).

Comment: I had an issue with it in my previous projects as it was not flexible enough

Comment: I think you should look more into it. It's very flexible.

Comment: Create dataclasses, in there create your database functions that implement stored procedures...

Comment: Thanx for the advice guys, its a good place to start for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of tools, extensions and frameworks that do a great job of creating the [Data Access Layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer) part of your code, most notably [SqlMetal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386987(v=vs.110).aspx) for [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx) or [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx).

If your database is Microsoft SQL Server, I recommend LINQ to SQL, it tends to generate much cleaner, better SQL, and the big plus is that it comes with .NET Framework so you won't need to deploy additional libraries.

If you're working with other database servers, Entity Framework is your best option.